# Using Google Test Adapter for Visual Studio with CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, googletest

A have a CMake-based project which uses Google Test for unit testing and I am using the Visual Studio generator to create my project/solution files.

I would like to be able to run my Google Test unit tests from the Visual Studio Test Explorer so that I can keep everything within the IDE. I heard about [Google Test Adapter](https://github.com/csoltenborn/GoogleTestAdapter) but obviously right out of the box it does not "know" where my tests are or how to run them.

How can I set this up to properly discover my tests? Can I just throw them in a directory and have GTA look for them that way?

Comment: Then create an issue on that repo and let the developers check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the [GoogleTestRunner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=markusl0.GoogleTestRunner) plugin in my projects.
This works pretty well, but notice that your executable needs a name, matches the regular expression "[Tt]est[s]{0,1}.exe" (e.g. MyProjectTest.exe).

By the way, this has no relation to cmake. But of cource, using cmake is no obstacle to use this plugin :).

Comment: Thanks, I missed the regular expression detail. It is working now

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the approach you are suggesting is not possible. Keep an eye on [this issue](https://github.com/csoltenborn/GoogleTestAdapter/issues/156)!